# Using Django's ManyToManyField with predefined intermediate model

Tags: django, many-to-many

Here are my models:

```
class Groups(models.Model):    
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,db_index=True)
    #Some other fields
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(Users, through='GroupAdmin')

class Users(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    #Some other fields...
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class GroupAdmin(models.Model):
    group_admin_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups)
```

Then I have this `ModelAdmin` defined

```
class GroupAdminAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ['user']

admin.site.register(GroupAdmin, GroupAdminAdmin)
```

For some reasons that I'm still unable to figure out I keep getting the following error on my web page whenever I try to work with this.

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/mysite
'GroupAdminAdmin.filter_horizontal[0]' must be a ManyToManyField.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot user the filter horizontal widget on a `ForeignKey` (which would hardly make any sense since it can only reference one object, while the widget's main goal is to easily select more than one object). 
You could use it on your admin for `Groups` for the field `admins` or you use an inline admin there to allow easy creation of new `Users` objects.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I'm still not getting the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` field though